# No veo el fallo en la línea 34 en teoría

Tags: c++

> Error en la linea 34, el fichero ya estaba tambien creado con que no se cual es el error
> en teoria  está en ficheros >> nombre+ apellido pero no se como ponerlo sino. Es un registro de gimnasio sencillo con que no creo que deba ser muy dificil. Ah y por cierto, no me estan dejando enviar esto antes porque dice que mi pregunta es la mayoria código y que necesito escribir un poco más.¿ Cómo me ahorro esto?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Usuario {
   public:
   string nombre;
   string apellidos;
   int edad;
   Usuario(string nombre, string apellidos, int edad){
       this->nombre = nombre;
       this->apellidos=apellidos;
       this->edad=edad;
   }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &p1, Usuario &p2) {
   p1<< p2.nombre + " "+ p2.apellidos  ; 
      return p1;
}
int main(){
   ifstream fichero;
   fichero.open("ficheros/usuarios.txt");
   string nombre;
   string apellidos;
   int edad;

   cout<<"Introduzca su nombre"<<"\n";
   cin>>nombre;
   cout<<"Introduzca sus apellidos"<<"\n";
   cin>>apellidos;
   cout<<"Introduza su edad"<<"\n";
   cin>>edad;
   fichero >> nombre +  apellidos;
   try{
       if(edad <=100){
           cout << "Registro completado con exito"<< "\n";
       } else {
           throw "error";        
       }
   }catch(...){
       cout<<"Edad invalida" <<endl;
   }

   fichero.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buen día, no puedes concatenar `strings` en la misma línea que `fstream`. Si deseas puedes utilizar `fichero >> nombre >> apellidos;` o crear una nueva variable, por ejemplo `string nombreCompleto` para concatenar `nombreCompleto = nombre + " " + apellidos;` y luego utilizarla en `fichero >> nombreCompleto;`

Comment: Sí puede concatenar `strings` en la misma línea, basta con usar paréntesis: `return p1<< (p2.nombre + " "+ p2.apellidos);`

Comment: Incluso sin paréntesis debería funcionar. El operador suma `+` tiene preferencia sobre el operador de inserción `<<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez del operador `+`:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &p1, Usuario &p2) {
   p1<< p2.nombre + " "+ p2.apellidos  ; 
      return p1;
}
```

Usa el operador de inserción:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &p1, Usuario &p2) {
   p1 << p2.nombre << " " << p2.apellidos; 
   return p1;
}
```

Aunque, en principio, el código debería funcionarte.

El problema que estás teniendo es que con el operador `+` estas creando un nuevo string *al vuelo* con el resultado de concatenar `p2.nombre` y `p2.apellido`. A continuación el programa intenta coger ese string y pasárselo a cout para que lo imprima.

Pues bien, el problema de los objetos creados al vuelo es que son *r-value*. Es decir, son elementos que no tienen nombre (no están almacenados en ninguna variable) y, por tanto, su vida es efímera. Este tipo de objetos tiene restricciones respecto a los *l-value*.

Una restricción, por ejemplo, es que un *r-value* no puede pasarse a una función como puntero o referencia no constante:

```
int func() { return 7; }

int func_no_const(int & value);
int func_const(int const& value);

func_no_const(func()); // ERROR
func_const(func()); // OK
```

Si te da error puede ser, probablemente, porque la implementación de la  STL que viene con tu compilador tiene algo raro:

- La precedencia de los operadores no está bien implementada (según el estándar, el operador + tiene más precedencia que el operador de inserción)
- La implementación de la sobrecarga del operador de inserción no ha marcado como constante el `string`
- Tu compilador tiene algún bug
- otros motivos ...